# Pig perform intersection of 2 bags which are sorted

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have loaded 2 sorted data bag from HDFS. Now I want to perform merge join or set intersect on them to return (3,Orphans of the Storm), (7,Muriel's Wedding) as result.

I am having some issues to get it working with datafu or pig mergejoin functionality.

I tried naive solution as mentioned below but it does not take advantage of my data being sorted.

```
vegas = LOAD 'vegas' USING PigStorage() AS (B1:bag{T1:tuple(id:int, name:chararray)});
macau = LOAD 'macau' USING PigStorage() AS (B2:bag{T2:tuple(id:int, name:chararray)});
vegast = FOREACH vegas GENERATE FLATTEN(vegas.$0) AS (id:int,name:chararray);
macaut = FOREACH hotel GENERATE FLATTEN(macau.$0) AS (id:int,name:chararray);

F = join vegast by id, macaut by id;
-- o/p: (3,Orphans of the Storm), (7,Muriel's Wedding)
-- describe vegas
--vegas: {B1: {T1: (id: int,name: chararray)}}
-- data for vegas
--({(3,Orphans of the Storm),(6,One Magic Christmas),(7,Muriel's Wedding),(8,Mother's Boys),(9,Nosferatu: Original Version)})

-- describe macau
--macau: {B1: {T1: (id: int,name: chararray)}}
--data for macau
--({(1,The Nightmare Before Christmas),(3,Orphans of the Storm),(4,The Object of Beauty),(7,Muriel's Wedding)})
```

Could someone please suggest what is the best way to find intersection of 2 bags which are sorted using pig ?

Comment: I solved the problem by Set operation using COGROUP. If anyone got SetIntersection in datafu or PigMergeJoin to work, please provide the hints.  http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2012/02/set-operations-in-apache-pig.html

Answer (score 0):

We at [Xplenty](http://www.xplenty.com) (Hadoop Platform as a Service) had the same issue with set operations on bags and we decided to go the easy path and implement the set operations in a JRuby UDF.

In order to execute it you'll need to install jruby on the nodes.

See here for code: https://gist.github.com/saggineumann/9804083

Answer (score 0):

If the relations are sorted by the join field, you can merge join them.

```
F = join vegast by id, macaut by id USING 'merge';
```

see more in the Pig docs: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/perf.html#merge-joins

Answer (score 0):

> If anyone got SetIntersection in datafu or PigMergeJoin to work, please provide the hints

[SetIntersect datafu guide](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide/set-operations.html). In case you are loading the following structure or achieved it after performing a join (note that bags must be sorted)

```
DESCRIBE relationWith2Bags
relationWith2Bags: {B1: {(id: int,name: chararray)},B2: {(id: int,name: chararray)}}
--let it contain only 1 tuple with sorted bags from the question
--B1: {(3,Orphans of the Storm),(6,One Magic Christmas),(7,Muriel's Wedding),(8,Mother's Boys),(9,Nosferatu: Original Version)}
--B2: {(1,The Nightmare Before Christmas),(3,Orphans of the Storm),(4,The Object of Beauty),(7,Muriel's Wedding)}

intersect = FOREACH relationWith2Bags GENERATE datafu.pig.sets.SetIntersect(B1, B2);
DUMP intersect
--({(3,Orphans of the Storm),(7,Muriel's Wedding)})
```